# Adding a CSS property to an HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to listen for a click event on a node list to add a CSS property, I don't want two nodes to have the property and I also want to toggle the CSS property on any of the node list with a second click, I can't seem to get the right guard clause to use, any Help.

`enter code here`

```js
const action = document.querySelectorAll ('.item');

const clearColor = function() {
  action.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove('item-color');
  })
}

action.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const target = e.target; 
    clearColor();
    target.classList.toggle("item-color")
  })
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
}

.item-color {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="action">
  <div class="item">pizza</div>
  <div class="item">rice</div>
  <div class="item">spaghetti</div>
  <div class="item">honey</div>
  <div class="item">cheese</div>
</div>
```

```
**strong text**
```

Comment: You call remove then toggle which will leave it on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with. Not the best but gets the job done.

```js
const action = document.querySelectorAll ('.item');

const clearColor = function() {
  action.forEach(function(item) {
    item.classList.remove('item-color');
  })
}

action.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    const target = e.target; 
    if(target.classList.contains("item-color")){
        clearColor();
    }else{
        clearColor();
        target.classList.toggle("item-color")
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
}

.item-color {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="action">
  <div class="item">pizza</div>
  <div class="item">rice</div>
  <div class="item">spaghetti</div>
  <div class="item">honey</div>
  <div class="item">cheese</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. There is a small problem here:

1. The user clicks on an item.
2. **All** items get their CSS class removed.
3. The clicked item gets a CSS class added *if it doesn't already exist*.

The subtle thing here is that "if it doesn't already exists" is **always true** for the clicked item, because you just removed its CSS class in step 2.

The solution is to *not remove the class* in step 2:

```
const clearColor = function(except) {
  action.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item === except) {
      return;
    }
    item.classList.remove('item-color');
  })
}

// ...

clearColor(target);
```

By filtering out the clicked element from the items you're removing the CSS classes from, `.toggle()` will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```js
const action = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

action.forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    item.classList.toggle('item-color');
    for(let i = 0; i < action.length; i++){
      if(e.currentTarget != action[i]){
        action[i].classList.remove('item-color');
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.item {
  margin: 10px;
}

.item-color {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
  <div class="action">
      <div class="item">pizza</div>
      <div class="item">rice</div>
      <div class="item">spaghetti</div>
      <div class="item">honey</div>
      <div class="item">cheese</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).